# Can I Copy an InDesign page along with the master page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I am trying to make a calendar, so I have downloaded a simple calendar template (InDesign Markup Document) which has 12 pages for each month

The 12 pages contains just text for each month with all the days on and the master contains the grid that the days go into.

I want to be able to copy everything on the page including the details from the master page and then paste them together into a new document.

No layers are locked but it won't let me select anything from the master page when I am on, let's say, page 1.

Is there a way to copy everything on that page or merge/ "expand" the master to be separate on every page?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is to **delete what you don't want, then save as a New Document**.

You can also choose `Override all Master Page Items` from the flyout menu on the **Pages Panel**. This will place the master items on the (highlighted/selected) page and unlink them from the Master Page(s).

Another possibility.....

You can actually **drag pages between InDesign documents**. Including Master Pages. Simply open more than one InDesign document, ensure they are separate windows and *not tabs*, then set them up so you can see both documents (`Window > Arrange > Tile`). Now you can just drag pages from the **Pages Panel** of document 1 to the window of document 2. This method is helpful when you want to copy several pages to a different document. You can drag as many pages as you highlight in the Pages Panel. However, you have to move Master Pages separately from other pages since you can't highlight both master and standard pages in the Pages Panel at the same time.

Comment: Yea, kind of went that route in the end. I just copied all from the master then pasted in place on each page and sent all to back and this has done the job. Thanks for the different methods

Answer (score 1):

If you know what items are from the master page, you can <kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> them to 'jump' them, releasing them from the master page (creating a so-called 'local override'). That way, you can copy them along with the regular items.

You might want to create a 2-step process: first, copy all regular items to your new document, then remove those from the original, jump all Master Page items and copy those as well.